# Quartus - synthesizing interfaces resulting in dangling nets

Tags: quartus

I have basic interfaces with modports as below in Quartus 20.1:

```
interface if_memory (
);

logic valid;
logic strobe;
logic wren;
logic [31:0] address;


modport client (
input valid,
output strobe, wren, address
);

modport host (
output valid,
input strobe, wren, address
);

endinterface
```

when I synthesize these interfaces connected between modules, I get the following warning:

```
Warning (12158): Entity "if_memory" contains only dangling pins
```

I connect these interfaces using the following basic assignments

```
if_memory if_memory();
assign some_strobe = if_memory.strobe;
assign some_wren = if_memory.wren;
assign some_address = if_memory.address;
```

With the some_block using the interface:

```
some_block some_block (
...
.if_memory(if_memory.client),
...
);
```

With some_block as

```
module some_block (

..
.
// memory interface
if_memory if_memory,
...
);
```

I've also tried if_memory.client as the port declaration, and passing in if_memory.

What is going on here? The only interfaces that do not have this dangling issue are clocked interfaces.

Note that what I have above matches Intel examples for interfaces - is there some setting that I am missing?

When i change the interfaces to ports - the designs work on the chip as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a literal result of the act of elaboration. When the line

if_memory if_memory();

is elaborated, it doesn't take into context *what* the logic nets are connected to at that level of hierarchy, or another.

If the declaration contained a port, such as:

if_memory if_memory(.clk(clk));

This warning would go away, because there would be a default net connected. Apparently the quartus assembler builds the modports at a later runtime.

While this is 'just how quartus works', this isn't a useful warning, and really doesn't contain useful information in this context. The warning is preceded by the elaboration step. In system verilog, it's common to have interfaces that just connect nets, in this case, there would be no way to not get this warning, even if all nets were connected in lower level modules even if modports attached to all nets.